# Xcode storyboard : how to access global color from storyboard

Tags: xcode, colors, uistoryboard

I want to access some custom colors from Xcode StoryBoard for any control. Which can be later easy changeable from one place for all controls. I know we can do it from code. But am looking for global color change from xcode storyboard.

For example if i assign one custom color for 10 labels from xcode storyboard with some color degree. If later i want to change the color degree i should not go to each 10 controls and change the degree from xcode storyboard.

As in Android we have colors.xml where you will define key and value for color. Then we can assign that key for many controls later we can change it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Xcode doesn't support anything like that as of Xcode 7.3.

You might be able to use [`UIAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/) to do less work, but that's code, not storyboard.

Comment: OK. But in my case some `UILabel` controls using different color degree and some `UILabel` are using different color. I don't think it is possible with `UIAppearance` for some `UILabel` different colors and for some other `UILabel` different color. Should i subclass `UILabel` for different scenarios and assign color code? Do you have any suggestions??

Comment: That subclassing idea sounds promising but I haven't tried it.